# Problem when trying to upload Rails static website to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am newbie with Heroku and trying to upload a static website to Heroku. Here is what I did with this one.

First, I made a static website named `Y` , and when I ran `localhost:3000`, it ran very ok.
Then I followed suggestions from internet, I changed my gemfile

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to 

`group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end`

and, change my `routes.rb` file like this

`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end`

But when I tried to run `heroku open` , it still give me this error

[image]

Sorry for my newbie's question, but I am stucking with this one and very confusing. Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: I suggest to follow this - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5

Answer (score 0):

Check your config/database.yml

You are using pg gem in production but your database.yml file is configured for sqlite3.

It's better to configure your app to use pg on both production and development as well.

You should change your gem file to use gem pg in development

Run bundle install

And then reconfigure your database.yml to use the pg database.

Then run
Rails db:create
Rails db:migrate

And dont forget to add our enviroment variables to heroku so that it can use the database.